# music is stuttering

Tags: 7.1-nougat, google-play-music, zte

So I have a zte z557bl running android 7.1.1 and ive been using google play music, but every time I would open a app, open the notification bar, lock my phone or go to the home screen, it would stop the music for a second and them the volume would change, or it would lag the music. does anyone know why its doing this?

Comment: Have you tried to use a different music player? Did the issue persist?

Comment: @Firelord yes i have, i've used the default music player, as well as spotify.

Comment: but the problem still exists